# Prove that matrix with parameter is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

I want to prove that the following matrix is positive definite for $a \in (0.5,1)$.
\begin{align}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a &  a \\ 
a & 1 & a \\ 
a & a & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y &  z  
\end{bmatrix} \cdot A \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\  z  
\end{bmatrix} = x^2+y^2+z^2+2a(yx+zx+zy)
\end{align}
Obviously, $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 0$, $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$. What's left to prove is that

\begin{align}2a(yx+zx+zy) > 0\end{align}

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually prove that $2a(yx + zx + zy)> 0$ because that isn't always the case.  However, you can say that in the event that $(yx + zx + zy) < 0,$
$$
\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2a(yx + zx + zy) &> 
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2(yx + zx + zy) \\
&= (x+y+z)^2 \geq 0
\end{align}
$$
Which leads to the desired conclusion.

Alternatively, it's enough to simply check that all leading principal sub-determinants of $A$ are positive (see the fourth explanation on [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations)).

Answer (score 3):

The matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if the principal determinants are positive hence if and only if:
$$1>0\; \text{and}\; 
\det \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\ 
a & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}=1-a^2>0\; \text{and}\;  
\det A =(2a+1)(a-1)^2>0\iff a\in(-0.5,1)
$$

Comment: Couldn't have answered better if I had answered! +1